# having problems adding commas to number while limiting it to only 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}


P = addCommas(P);
$("#monthly_result").html(P.toFixed(2));
```

I left out the P calculations, so keep in mind it is outputting a number in the thousands with decimals.

I got the function from stack and it works well adding commas to numbers in the thousands. However when I tried to limit the value to 2 decimal places it doesnt output anything.

Thanks

Comment: Your code would work if you convert the number to a fixed string before you add the commas. toFixed doesn't work on strings. If you do that, you don't need to split on the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is pretty simple but would be what your looking for:

http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481

Example:

```
$("#monthly_result").html(number_format('1234.56', 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

toFixed is not available for strings (which your addCommas function returns).
simple solution would be to convert the number to a float by using parseFloat and then cut the decimal places using toFixed and convert back to string to proceed with your function.

for a fixed number of decimal places, something along the lines of:

```
function addCommas(num) {
  var num = parseFloat(num).toFixed(2)+'',
      rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3}[\d,]*\.\d{2})/;

  while (rgx.test(num)) {
    num = num.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return num;
}
```

In this case, `addCommas(61423.34512);` would return `"61,423.35"`. I'd recommend using the number_format function posted by Robert for some extra formatting options, though.